# Where does gVim find font options for its `guifont` pick list?

Tags: gvim, font, cygwin, x11

In gvim, **`:set guifont=*`** brings up a **GUI panel** from which one can choose a font family, weight, slant, and size.  **Where does gVim find these fonts?**

I'm using Cygwin's X-windows.  While the scheme for making fonts available to X-window clients has always come across as complicated to me, I wonder if the fonts of which gVim are aware are the same as those made available by X-windows to all clients?

I found this question [posted before,](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/dn1CXxsdQyU) but no answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a speculative answer only.

I suspect that `gvim` has its own set of fonts.  Here are the unbolded,
unslanted monospace fonts, manually transcribed from the selection
list from `:set guifont=*`:

```
Consolas Regular
DejaVu Sans Mono Book
Inconsolata Medium
Liberation Mono Regular
Lucida Console Regular
Monospace Regular
Source Code Pro Regular
Source Code Pro Medium
```

The following are the X-windows fonts.  There is very little overlap.
So unless there is some aliasing, the set of font families seem to be
different:

```
xlsfonts | sed -e 's/-.*//' | sort -u

10x20
12x24
12x24kana
12x24romankana
5x7
5x8
6x10
6x12
6x13
6x13bold
6x9
7x13
7x13bold
7x13euro
7x13eurobold
7x14
7x14bold
8x13
8x13bold
8x16
8x16kana
8x16romankana
9x15
9x15bold
a14
cursor
decw$cursor
decw$session
fixed
hanzigb16fs
hanzigb16st
hanzigb24st
heb6x13
heb8x13
k14
kana14
kanji16
kanji24
lucidasans
lucidasanstypewriter
micro
nil2
olcursor
olglyph
r14
r16
r24
rk14
rk16
rk24
variable
```

The very odd thing is that `/usr/share/fonts` contains folders with names that correspond to font families:

```
adobe-source-code-pro/  dejavu/       liberation/  terminus/
adobe-source-sans-pro/  inconsolata/  microsoft/   urw-base35/
```

While they resemble the `gvim` font names more than the X11 font names, none of the folders contain a file that looks like any variation of lucida.  Lucida appears in both `gvim` and X11 lists of fonts above.  There is no file with a name containing the string `alias` in any of these folders.

**Additional information from searching for X11 fonts**

In a Cygwin package for font aliases, I found that the [usual alias
files are
obsolete](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/font-alias.html). The
entire package has been replaced by `xorg-x11-fonts-misc`, along with
[many other font
packages](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=xorg-x11-fonts-misc&arch=x86_64).
Package
[`xorg-x11-fonts-misc`](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fxorg-x11-fonts-misc%2Fxorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.5-4&grep=xorg-x11-fonts-misc)
contains "X11 core fonts" in folder tree `/usr/share/X11/fonts`,
binned into the following categories:

```
100dpi/  75dpi/  encodings/  misc/  Type1/
```

The `misc` folder in particular seems to contain the font family names
for many of the above families from `xlsfonts`, e.g., a series of
files `10x20-ISO8859-*.pcf.gz`, where `*` seems to be merely a file
sequencing number rather than an `xfontsel` parameter.  From `find *
-type f | grep -i luc`, none of the gzipped font files in the
`/use/share/X11/fonts` tree seem to have a name containing the string
`luc` (for Lucida).  I tried peering in the gunzipped *.pcf files, but
they are binary.

Using `cygcheck -lv` and searching for (i) `/usr/share/fonts` and/or
(ii) `/use/share/X11/fonts`, it becomes obvious that the fonts
in these two directories come from different packages.  I am now
floundering in the X-windows font scheme documentation to find a way
to make fonts in folder (i) available to X-windows (e.g., as
`.Xresources` fonts for `xterm`).  Currently, `xfontsel` does not show
the fonts available to `gvim`, at least not by their `gvim` names.
The reason for consolidating the two sets of fonts is that, after
spending a lot of time finding a good set of fonts for `gvim`, I would
like to be able to just use those fonts for `xterm` rather than
searching through an entirely new (and seemingly bigger) pool of
X11 fonts.

As it turns out, some of the font category folders in `/use/share/X11/fonts`
contain alias definitions that match the font family names
from `xlsfonts`:

```
head $(find * -name '*alias*')

==> 100dpi/fonts.alias <==
lucidasans-bolditalic-8 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-11-80-100-100-p-69-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-10 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-14-100-100-100-p-90-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-12 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-17-120-100-100-p-108-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-14 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-20-140-100-100-p-127-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-18 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-25-180-100-100-p-159-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-24 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-34-240-100-100-p-215-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bold-8 -b&h-lucida-bold-r-normal-sans-11-80-100-100-p-70-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bold-10 -b&h-lucida-bold-r-normal-sans-14-100-100-100-p-89-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bold-12 -b&h-lucida-bold-r-normal-sans-17-120-100-100-p-108-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bold-14 -b&h-lucida-bold-r-normal-sans-20-140-100-100-p-127-iso8859-1

==> 75dpi/fonts.alias <==
lucidasans-bolditalic-8 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-8-80-75-75-p-49-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-10 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-10-100-75-75-p-67-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-12 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-12-120-75-75-p-79-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-14 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-14-140-75-75-p-92-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-18 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-18-180-75-75-p-119-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bolditalic-24 -b&h-lucida-bold-i-normal-sans-24-240-75-75-p-151-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bold-8 -b&h-lucida-bold-r-normal-sans-8-80-75-75-p-50-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bold-10 -b&h-lucida-bold-r-normal-sans-10-100-75-75-p-66-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bold-12 -b&h-lucida-bold-r-normal-sans-12-120-75-75-p-79-iso8859-1
lucidasans-bold-14 -b&h-lucida-bold-r-normal-sans-14-140-75-75-p-92-iso8859-1

==> misc/fonts.alias <==
! $Xorg: fonts.alias,v 1.3 2000/08/21 16:42:31 coskrey Exp $
fixed        -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
variable     -*-helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1
5x7          -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-1
5x8          -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-iso8859-1
6x9          -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--9-90-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
6x10         -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
6x12         -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--12-110-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
6x13         -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
6x13bold     -misc-fixed-bold-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
```

This fills in the picture a bit more about where `xlsfonts` gets its
fonts, but not how the fonts in `/usr/share/fonts` (where `gvim` likely
gets its fonts) can be "registered" for use by other X-windows clients.