# Choose Gvim font that maps pixel-to-pixel with display?

Tags: gvim, font

I recently bought a Windows 10 laptop, TravelMate P2410-G2-M.  The resolution is set to the native physical resolution of the display.

However, my Gvim text displays with some pixel columns/rows smeared over multiple display pixel column/rows:

[image]

**How can I identify fonts whose pixels map one-to-one with the pixels on the display?**

The above is a general question, but the specific system I'm using is configured as follows:

- Using Windows 10 and 64-bit Cygwin's X-windows, downloaded and installed circa start of 2020
- The above screen shot of bleeding pixels was using the Gvim option guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 9

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Windows you should specify your font using separate fields for the font face, height and so on.

For instance, perhaps this will work better:

```
set guifont=Lucida_Console:h9
```

See [`:help E244`](https://vimhelp.org/gui.txt.html#E244) for the details of the fields you can set for the font.

In particular, take a look at the `q` parameter, for font quality, which includes settings such as PROOF, DRAFT, ANTIALIASED, NONANTIALIASED, or CLEARTYPE. Perhaps using a NONANTIALIASED font quality is what you're after?

Finally, consider using a font picker, which you can launch with:

```
:set guifont=*
```

You might be able to tweak details of the font in the font dialog and it's possible that you'll get a preview of what the font will look like in that dialog too.

Once you're happy with a selection, you can query `:set guifont?` to save that selection to your vimrc file.

Comment: Thanks, filbranden.  I did some limited experimentation, and adding `:q<*anything*>` after the font name makes the font become the same spaced-out look as when I provide an illegal font name. The `:q` qualifier might not apply to X11, even on a Windows machine. I had the same result with `Lucida\ Console\ Regular:9:qNOTANTIALIASED`.

Comment: The font specified in my original question was chosen from font picker `set guifont=*`. It's not always easy to tell how it looks from the sample that it provides, and it might be related to the colors that I use (the font picker uses black on white). I also used `xfontsel` in the past, but it's really complicated, with all its fields.  It's the nuclear option, but I really was trying to focus my question on how to identify fonts that map pixel-to-pixel to the display.

Comment: For example, is there a naming convention for them? A font family name?  Is this complicated by the use of X11 on Windows? I'm not sure if antialiasing means the same thing; in DSP, it means low pass filtering to remove artifacts from sampling. You can have mismatched sampling without antialiasing (which would be really bad), but I'm really shooting for matched sampling so that antialiasing is not needed.

Comment: Ah I missed you're on X11. Yes, this definitely complicates things a lot more! The answer I wrote was assuming you were on a native Windows build... Any reason why you're not using one?

Comment: I imagine you'll have similar trouble with other X11 applications, so maybe consider asking on Unix&Linux SE... Or, better yet, Superuser SE, there you might get expert advice on X11, Cygwin and such...

Comment: Yeah, it's the same antialiasing from DSP, only applied to 2-D graphics. You get the effect of blurry edges with grayscale pixels to make up for the lack of resolution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing and also google for "font antialiasing", you'll see tons of results, it's a really common term.

Comment: I suspect that if I use a font that was meant to map pixel-to-pixel with the display, then anti-aliasing is unnecessary and won't be used.  I have used Gvim for windows in the past, but I find that there is tremendous benefit from the combination of Gvim, bash, and the unix utilities that bash calls.  I even spent endless days in decades past trying to find ways to have Gvim for Windows shell out to Cygwin's bash, but always ran into trip-ups.  I no longer think that is worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Superuser SE.  I will give it a shot. One of my concerns is that it might be a problem with the interaction between X11 and Windows, i.e., specific to Cygwin, wherein X11's idea of the pixel grid doesn't match the actual hardware.

Comment: Thankfully, there are indications against this, e.g., my `xterm` fonts don't exhibit this.  But the `xterm` fonts aren't the same as the Gvim fonts.  And this is the odd thing, partly behind why I'm hesitant to use `xfontsel` -- the available fonts [seem to be different](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22646/where-does-gvim-find-font-options-for-its-guifont-pick-list).  The world of font management can be very complicated and scary.  It just looks like a very Gvim problem in my environment, though it might very well be due to the fonts available to Gvim rather than Gvim itself.

Comment: I use native Windows gvim and have configured it to use Cygwin bash fairly seamlessly. Whether it would work as well for you depends on whether you hit the same pain points as I had been hitting. Do you remember the specifics on any of the tougher issues you had that convinced you to use Cyg/X11/gvim instead?

Comment: Not particularly, no.  It was years ago.  I think it was a combination of quoting complex bash commands with piping and escaping, and possibly a dash of how to ensure that my bashrc/profile/aliases were run.

Comment: Sounds like some of them are the usual suspects. I don't really run into issues anymore but I can't say I run many commands with really tricky quoting/escaping from there (though I do in Bash itself).