# Why does Gvim not see my X11 fonts?

Tags: gvim, font, cygwin, x11

After going blind from using Gvim with non-bitmapped fonts, I tried to narrow my question from the previous attempts [(1)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22646/where-does-gvim-find-font-options-for-its-guifont-pick-list/22650#22650) and [(2)](https://superuser.com/questions/1530098/choose-gvim-font-that-maps-pixel-to-pixel-with-display) (with older attempts going back years).  Specifically, I wanted to find a means to force visibility of X11 fonts to Gvim. [This X11 font info page](http://linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/XWindow-User-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.2) explains that I need bitmapped fonts to avoid the horrible mixing of brightness from adjacent (logical) pixels, and even identifies the font directories.

Unfortunately, Gvim doesn't recognize such fonts.  For example, my `xterm` can be set to (say) `-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-80-iso8859-1`, but if I set Gvim's `guifont` to this, it just defaults to the same spaced-out font that it does when supplied with an unrecognized font specification.

Web search indicates that one reason why the fonts may not be visible to Gvim is that the host folder is not in the "font path".   X11 fonts are so complicated that I could not find out how to display the font path (I can set it using `xset`). Further web search says that it is set in an `xorg.conf` file, but a `find` command issued for `xorg.conf*` yields nothing (an Ubuntu page suggested possible path `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`).  Further search unearths frequent mention that `xorg.conf` is no longer used these days.

Since I'm using Cygwin, I fortunately found a [font page](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/Xserver.1.html) indicating that the font path is set in `/etc/X11/fontpath.d/`.  At last, something that actually rings true in my system:

```
$ ls -l /etc/X11/fontpath.d/ | sed -e 's/.*[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] //'
total 5
terminus:unscaled -> /usr/share/fonts/terminus/
xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi:unscaled:pri=30 -> /usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi/
xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi:unscaled:pri=20 -> /usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi/
xorg-x11-fonts-misc:unscaled:pri=10 -> /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc/
xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 -> /usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/
```

I've unsuccessfully tried to peek into the files therein before, but I'm not sure if that would actually help.  What the above shows is that the idea of X11 bitmapped fonts in the font path is satisfied, and the reason why Gvim can't see them must be some other reason.  This is a problem that is very specific to Gvim, and I have thus far been unable to find anything online for what determines the fonts that Gvim sees.

Gvim has been around for decades -- surely this is a well-known detail?

**Helpful background found**

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338047/how-does-fontconfig-actually-work) explanation of `fontconfig` fills in some of my void of knowledge.  It tells me that I want to avoid Type 1 fonts.  Using `fc-list`, I found that the "recognized" (registered?) fonts include those in the folder subtrees rooted in *both* `/usr/share/fonts and`/usr/share/X11/fonts.  I am disturbed by the phrase "XFT allows scaling of the old bitmap fonts to look like Type1 fonts". Maybe that's why my fonts looks so bad, but it doesn't explain why this
only afflicts Gvim.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6710/how-can-i-use-bitmap-fonts-in-gvim) page on *using bitmap fonts in Gvim* is very relevant, but I have no `/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf` to remove and no `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf` to link.  Indeed, I have no `/etc/fonts/conf.avail` folder.

The above page is linked to by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90001/how-can-i-activate-bitmap-fonts) page on *activating bitmap fonts,* but I don't have `70-force-bitmaps` to link to either.

I also came across the suggestion to set the `antialias` option, but in my Gvim, that option is apparently not supported.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font) Wikipedia page on *computer fonts* says that PCF is bitmap, and [this](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/Fonts-look-ugly-in-X-with-gvim-td34119.html) Cygwin/Gvim page corroborates this in saying "You're better off using the PCF form of the font".  However, its suggestion of such a font is `:set gfn=LucidaTypewriter\ 17`, which definitely doesn't look bitmapped, judging by the foreground/background color averaging on some pixels.  It may be the case that the underlying font is bitmapped, but there's scaling/antialiasing occuring between the font itself and Gvim, possibly done by X.

The [Fonts in X11R7.5](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/fonts/fonts.html) page contains an [Installing fonts](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/fonts/fonts.html#SEC-INSTALLING) section.  It contains a [Troubleshooting](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/fonts/fonts.html#SEC-TROUBLESHOOTING-CORE) subsection listing the extensions of bitmap fonts (and *freetype* fonts, which I'm not interested in right now):

- "bitmap": bitmap fonts ('*.bdf', '*.pcf' and '*.snf');
- "freetype": TrueType fonts ('*.ttf' and '*.ttc'), OpenType fonts ('*.otf' and '*.otc') and Type 1 fonts ('*.pfa' and '*.pfb').

I found the extensions of files in the `/usr/share/fonts` `/usr/share/X11/fonts` file trees, taking care to preserve extensions of gzipped files:

```
find /usr/share/fonts/ /usr/share/X11/fonts/ -type f \
| sed -e 's=.*\(\.[[:alnum:]]\{1,3\}.gz\)$=\1=' \
      -e '/\.gz$/!s=.*\(\.[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}$\)=\1=' \
| sort -u | tr '\n' ' '

    .afm .alias .dir .enc.gz .otf .pcf.gz
    .pfa .pfb .scale .t1 .ttf .uuid
```

Comparing to the above `bitmap` and `freetype` file extensions above, we see that the only bitmap fonts have `*.pcf` extension.  All the others are `freetype`, with *exception* of extensions `*.afm`, `*.alias`, `*.dir`, `*.scale`, and `*.uuid`.  Based on the extensions alone, we can speculate that all these exceptions serve purpose other than housing actual fonts (well, perhaps `*.afm` looks like it may be a font).

The folders containing the identified `bitmap` fonts are:

```
find /usr/share/fonts/ /usr/share/X11/fonts/
    -type f -name '*.pcf.gz' \
| sed -e 's=/[^/]*$==' | sort -u

    /usr/share/fonts/terminus
    /usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi
    /usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi
    /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc

ls \
/usr/share/fonts/terminus \
/usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi \
/usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi \
/usr/share/X11/fonts/misc
```

The `ls` command shows that only the `terminus` folder contains fonts with a common filename root, e.g.,

```
/usr/share/fonts/terminus:
fonts.dir
fonts.scale
ter-112b.pcf.gz
ter-112n.pcf.gz
ter-114b.pcf.gz
<...etc...>
```

All the other folders contain a diversity of fonts with different font names.  I was hoping that I can easily find bitmap font names matching those from `:set guifont=*`, but the only easily recognizable Gvim font name is `terminus` -- or rather, `Terminus` in the `guifont` picker.  It seems to be free from the mixing of brightness between foregroound and background, indicating that not only is it a bitmap font, but that it also behaves like a bitmap font in Cygwin's X11.  However, it is not a good looking font.  :(

Comment: I think you should consider running the native Windows gvim and try to integrate it with Cygwin. Messing with X11 on Windows is likely to be quite frustrating I'd expect... See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12654100/9447571 for some ideas on how to use Windows gvim with cygwin. (Though that might not be enough... YMMV. Maybe you'll need more searches to get that integration going.) Also maybe look into WSL and WSL2 in Windows as possible replacements for Cygwin, I heard they're awesome and quite well integrated into Windows.

Comment: I did that for years.  It takes too much time trying to force it to work with bash and Cygwin unix utilities.

Comment: I wonder if you can build Vim from source inside Cygwin, but still enable Windows as the GUI toolkit... Googling didn't show useful results, but at least in theory I'd expect it might be possible to do it.

Comment: https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.win32-api

Comment: I'm sure that it is possible, but not being a developer, it is beyond what I can achieve with the available time.  It's really quite odd.  I never would have imagined that the information about where Gvim finds its fonts would be so elusive.  Unless it's not configurable, i.e., is a parameter specified when it is compiled.  That is not what I would expect from an X-windows client

Comment: Yeah sorry, X11 makes my head hurt and Cygwin just adds one extra layer on top of it... In fact in most Linux distros GVim uses GTK so gets its fonts from GTK and not even X11. (The fact that GTK has its own separate font system should tell you a lot about X11's...) I'll see if I can get a Windows VM somewhere and try to get that mixed build, Cygwin Vim, but using Windows GUI libraries for display.

Comment: Thank, but don't do it just for me.  Can you contribute your work to Cygwin?

Comment: One thing at a time!  First figure out if it's possible and how to do it... Got a VM, installing Cygwin now... Stay tuned!

Comment: `It takes too much time trying to force it to work with bash and Cygwin unix utilities` BTW. I use native GVim with MSYS2 stuff and it works quite well (except a couple of things I had to fix, but once it's done, it's done). I don't expect Cygwin will be much different. Also, only native GVim supports DirectX text rendering (see `:h 'renderoptions'`) what, I believe, is essential to make it look good on Windows.

Comment: At the moment, I've focused on why Gvim can't see the X-windows fonts.  If it can see them and displays a font poorly, but that font is well displayed by `xterm`, then I think we can conclude that it is a rendering problem.  Especially if it is a bitmapped font.

Comment: With WSL2, there's really no reason to bother with Cygwin.  You can launch the native Windows gvim straight from bash easily, and [as of a couple days ago](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/the-initial-preview-of-gui-app-support-is-now-available-for-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/) you can also run the Linux GTK Vim just as easily.

Comment: I may switch to WSL2 one day, but I rely on many tools that come with Cygwin, many of which use X-windows.